# Prepared Statement en Java: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Tengo problemas con la importación del prepared statement. Tengo una clase que hace la conexión, pero no puedo utilizar el prepare statement. Estoy utilizando la librería mysql-connector.

Este es mi clase de conexion:

```
//Esta clase sirve para conectar a la base de datos
package conexion;

import com.sun.jdi.connect.spi.Connection;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;




public class Conexion {
    private static Connection CONN;
    private static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String USER = "********";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "********";
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://****/******";
    
    public Conexion (){
        CONN = null;
        
    }
    
    //Metodo de retorno conexion 
    public Connection getConnection(){
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
            CONN = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
             
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error al conectar con la base de datos", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
             System.out.println("Error al conectar con la base de datos"+ex.getMessage());
             System.exit(0);
        }
        return CONN;
    }
    
    //Metodo para desconectar de bd
     public void desconectar () throws IOException{
         CONN.close();
         
     }
  
            }
```

Esta es mi clase clientes:

```
package logica;


import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
import conexion.Conexion;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import  java.sql.ResultSet;


/**
 *
 * @author agusm
 */
public class Cls_Clientes {
    private final String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO users (nombre, apellido, email, password) values (?,?,?,?)";
    private final String SQL_SELECT = "SELECT * FROM users";
    private PreparedStatement PS;
    private DefaultTableModel DT;
    private ResultSet RS;
    private final Conexion CN;
    
    public Cls_Clientes(){
        PS = null;
        CN = new Conexion();
    }
    
    private DefaultTableModel setTitulos (){
        DT = new DefaultTableModel();
        DT.addColumn("Nombre");
        DT.addColumn("Apellido");
        DT.addColumn("Email");
        DT.addColumn("Contraseña");
        
        return DT;
    }
    
    public int insertDatosClientes (String nom, String ape, String email, String pass) throws IOException{
        int res =0;
        try {
            PS =CN.getConnection().prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT);
            PS.setString(1, nom);
            PS.setString(2, ape);
            PS.setString(3, email);
            PS.setString(4, pass);
            
            res = PS.executeUpdate();
            if (res > 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro Guradado");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Error al guardar los datos en la bd: "+e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            PS = null;
            CN.desconectar();
        }
        return res;
    }
    
    public DefaultTableModel getDatosClientes () throws IOException{
        try {
            setTitulos();
            PS =CN.getConnection().prepareStatement(SQL_SELECT);
            RS = PS.executeQuery();
            Object [] fila = new Object[10];
            while (RS.next()) {
                fila[0] = RS.getString(1);
                fila[1] = RS.getString(2);
                fila[2] = RS.getString(3);
                fila[3] = RS.getString(4);
             
                DT.addRow(fila);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error al listar los datos"+e.getMessage());
        }finally{
            PS = null;
            RS=null;
            CN.desconectar();
        }
        return DT;
    }

    
}
```

Sigo teniendo problemas con el PreparedStatement, incluso cuando he cambiado la importación desde `import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;` a `import java.sql.PreparedStatement;`. No sé cuál puede ser el error.

El error que se presenta es cannot find symbol. Y estoy usando connector 5.1

Comment: Qué problema? Qué mensaje de error?

Comment: [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) es una interfaz de `java.sql`, por lo que el `import` que aplica es **`import java.sql.PreparedStatement;`**. Dicho eso, ¿cuál es el problema o error? Otra cosa, `Class.forName` es obsoleto desde JDBC 4, no sé si usas una versión superior a la v. 4 de JDBC.

Comment: Estoy utilizando la versión la versión 5.1

Comment: El mensaje de error es `cannot find symbol`

Comment: El `import` no es así: `import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;` sino así: **`import java.sql.PreparedStatement;`**

Comment: @A.Cedano sigue dando error la linea `PS =CN.getConnection().prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT);` con cannot find symbol, incluso cuando agregué la linea que me mostraste

Comment: Es que, a ver, tienes que revisar las cosas que estás importando. Por ejemplo, ¿esto que es: `import com.sun.jdi.connect.spi.Connection;`? ¿¿¿ ??? Si vas a trabajar con una conexión a la base de datos vía JDBC, lo que tienes que importar es esto: **`import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;`**